# AWS CloudFormation error with network interface

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I get this error whenever I launch my stack

> (Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be
>   specified on the same request (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID:....))

and the status in `Aws console` is: `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`

How I can solve this error?

```
EC2Instance:
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
Properties:
  SecurityGroups: 
    - !Ref SecurityGroup
  KeyName : !Ref EC2Key
  AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
  ImageId: ami-01410f0e8f8b1acca
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  NetworkInterfaces:
    - DeviceIndex: '0'
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
```

Comment: The error means what it says. You can't specify both a network interface and a security group property. You must choose one or the other. If you go with the network interface, you specify the SG within that interface.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason why you want to specify network interface?

If all you need to accomplish is to deploy the instance into the specific subnet, just drop the `NetworkInterfaces` part and specify the subnet for the instance itself.

```
EC2Instance:
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
Properties:
  SecurityGroups: 
    - !Ref SecurityGroup
  KeyName : !Ref EC2Key
  AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
  ImageId: ami-01410f0e8f8b1acca
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
```