# how to create a template ec2 related to vpc

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a template ec2 related with vpc but fails when I try to create ec2 with networkinterface. The error says 'the request is not supported ec2...'

I have this template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  DevVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: false
      EnableDnsHostnames: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: DevStackVpc
  DevSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: DevVpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: DevSubnet
  WebApplicationServerSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: DevVpc
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP and SSH access
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: WebApplicationServer Service Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  WebApplicationServer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fc61db8544a617ed
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: WebApplicationServer
      KeyName: myKeyName
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - GroupSet:
          - Ref: WebApplicationServerSG
          AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeviceIndex: '0'
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          SubnetId:
            Ref: DevSubnet
```

which is the error? the vpc creates  right, subnet, security group, the instance is fine but network interface is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "network interface is wrong"? In what way its wrong?

Comment: Your template worked perfectly fine for me! I ran it in us-east-1 and had to remove the Keypair, but otherwise no changes necessary. Please try again and tell us the _exact_ error message, and which resource it appeared against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to specify the Network interface.

If all you need to accomplish is to deploy the instance into the specific subnet, just drop the NetworkInterfaces part and specify the subnet for the instance itself. See [AWS CloudFormation error with network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950969/aws-cloudformation-error-with-network-interface/60006766#60006766)